# Add penalty parameter to linear program pulp

Tags: python, pulp

I'm writing a LP problem in pulp python. I'm not new to LP but I am to pulp. So far I got a couple of constraints that are implemented correctly. They are simple and I know how they work. The problem is about assigning containers to voyages;

```
# All containers asigned to only 1 voyage
for i in cntrs:
    prob += lpSum([x[(i,v)] for v in voyages]) <= 1
    
# Contaienr to right destination
for v in voyages:
    prob += lpSum([x[(i,v)] * posibleDest.loc[i,v] for i in cntrs]) == 1

# Weight capacity of voyages
for v in voyages:
    for b in barges:
        prob += lpSum([weight[i] * x[(i,v)] for i in cntrs]) <= voyWCap[v]
        
# Type capacity of voyages
for c in cats:
    for v in voyages:
        prob += cntrCat.loc[i,c] * x[(i,v)] <= bargeCATCAP.loc[c,b] * voyBarge.loc[b,v]
        
# TEU cap of voyages
for v in voyages:
    for b in barges:
        prob += lpSum([cntrTEU[i] * x[(i,v)] for i in cntrs]) <= voyTEUCap[v]
```

I tested the program and it works just fine, however I'm stuck at a particular part. I want to add an parameter 'Tardy' which, if the container arrives to late/early, it gives the container a 'penalty value'. My objective function is to minimize unused space, so adding the sum of penalties times a big number should 'push' the program into trying to get everything in the right time window.

Now my problem; I know this works, only not how to program it.

What I've done so far;

My objective function is as follows

```
prob += lpSum([(TEUcap[b] * voyBarge.loc[b,v]) - (x[(i,v)] * cntrTEU[i]) + Tardy[i] * M]  
              for i in cntrs
              for b in barges
              for v in voyages)
```

Where M is a very big number

I've created a dictionary (Tardy) with 0's and a loop to fill that dictionary;

```
Tardy = dict.fromkeys(cntrs,0)

for i in cntrs:
    for v in voyages:
        if cntrDest.dot(voyArive).loc[i,v] != 0:
            if cntrDest.dot(voyArive).loc[i,v] * x[(i,v)] <= (cntrOpen.dot(voyDest)).loc[i,v] * x[(i,v)]:
                Tardy[i] = 1
            elif cntrDest.dot(voyArive).loc[i,v] * x[(i,v)] >= (cntrClose.dot(voyDest)).loc[i,v] * x[(i,v)]:
                Tardy[i] = 1
            else:
                Tardy[i] = 0
```

In words: most of my parameters are matrices, if there is a value (not 0) for

```
cntrDest.dot(voyArive).loc[i,v]
```

It means there is an arival datetime for container i on voyage v, if this value is greater than close datetime, or smaller than the open datetime, that container should get a penalty (Tardy[container] =1)

Because x is a LpVariable

```
x[(i,v)]
```

is always 0 before the problem is solved, therefore, tardy is always 1.

I think I have to 'paste' a prob+= in somewhere, but I can't figure out how to let the program take it into account. If anyone could help me make it work, or have another suggestion on how to program it, that would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't formulate your model "conditionally"...  Meaning `Tardy` is a variable in your model and you cannot assign values to it within a conditional statement (if-elif-else) inside of a linear program because the value of the dependent variables (`x` in this case) is not known when the problem is formulated and handed over to the solver, so we need to try something else and re-formulate that.

It isn't totally clear how you are handling times within your model, but it *appears* that the containers have due-dates and the voyages have arrival times, which would be the basis of calculating `Tardy`.  So, you should introduce `Tardy[i]` as a non-negative real value and just constrain it to be larger than the difference between the arrival time and the due date.  That assumes that container 'i' goes on that particular voyage 'v'.  So, we need to multiply that delta by the selection binary variable `x` to only apply in the case of selection.  In pseudo-code:

```
Tardy[i] >= (arrival_time[v] - due_time[i]) * x[i,v]
```

and then build that into your pulp model for each i,v in the model